# Updating WPF Animation Easing function at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I am working on a WPF app where I would like to be able to change the Easing function at runtime. This could be done either in code behind or via a combobox selection. I just can't figure out how to do it.
Here is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAnimationExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAnimationExample"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="EllipseEasing" TargetType="Ellipse">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue"/>
        
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation To="760" Duration="0:0:6"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" FillBehavior="Stop"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Name="VerticalAnimation" To="330" Duration="0:0:6"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" FillBehavior="Stop">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <BounceEase EasingMode="Easeout"></BounceEase>
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
   <Canvas Name="Canvas">
        <Ellipse Name="MainEllipse" Style="{StaticResource EllipseEasing}" Canvas.Top="60" MouseEnter="Ellipse_MouseEnter" />
    </Canvas>
</StackPanel>
```

The part I wish to alter at runtime is

```
<DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
    <BounceEase EasingMode="Easeout"></BounceEase>
</DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
```

Thoughts? As always TIA.

Comment: Make the easingfunction a resource. Reference that using dynamicresource. You can then set this.Resources["kkkk"] = new someothereasingfunction.

Comment: Templates are only applied when ui is created but i think this approach will still reference a concrete resource so switching it out wil probably wirk.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. TBH I don't know how to make the easingfunction a resource.